# why is df.fillna() only filling some rows and the first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, fillna

Trying to fill all empty spots rows and columns with [], however fillna() will only do some rows and the first column. My code has worked in previous runs so I'm not sure what happened.

```
    df = df.fillna(value = "[]")
    print(df[['keywords']])
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\user\dfexport.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

When looking at the csv file it looks like:[export.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT0Tq.png)

The print statement looks like:[print(df[['keywords]])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW6ea.png)

Comment: Perhaps some of those cells are empty strings instead of NaN

Comment: That would make the most sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['',''], []]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.fillna(value = "[]")
print(df)
```

Comment: This does work but something odd is going on it will replace with Nan but when printing the data frame instead of having a value of None or Nan it is completely empty nothing in it.

Comment: in this line df = df.fillna(value = "[]")  replace [] with None or Nan as this df = df.fillna(value = "None") . Does this help ?

Comment: It didnt help but the reason the empty string didn't work was some had whitespace or new line etc...

Comment: Try this df.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', np.nan, inplace=True,regex=True)
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

Comment: what I got to work was a regex replace looking for all instances of white space and another looking for any instance of \n\r etc..